# US-PHILIPPINE Flight

Tags: canada, us-citizens, layovers, transit-visas

I will have US-PHILIPPINE flight, with same flight. With 2 hrs layover in Vancouver, Canada. I have US passport. Do I need a transit pass to enter Canada?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you hold a US passport, you [do not need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=US&result=3&message=0&standard=3&q3=) to transit through Canada.

Comment: Indeed, most US citizens don't need a visa toventer Canada for most purposes.